# Initialize media player only if query string parameter is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint page that has a hyperlink which points to a video clip. Clicking on the link will play the video in an overlay window (uses Silverlight). If Silverlight runtime is not present, it displays the "install Silverlight" prompt. When the page is invoked with a `IsDlg=1` query string, the hyperlink is hidden (it is in the left navigation bar), and only the main content page is shown. But I still get the "install Silverlight" prompt. I want to get rid of the prompt when `IsDlg=1` is present.

Below is the relevant javascript code on the page. I've modified it slightly to initialize the media player only if `IsDlg=1` is not present. But it is not working as expected. Any ideas?

```
// original code
 $(function () {
        mediaPlayer.createOverlayPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.attachToMediaLinks(document.getElementById('videoList'), ['wmv', 'avi', 'mp4']);
    });

// modified code
    $(function () {
        var field = 'IsDlg';
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1) {

        } else {
            mediaPlayer.createOverlayPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.attachToMediaLinks(document.getElementById('videoList'), ['wmv', 'avi', 'mp4']);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the HTML which embeds the Silverlight control is present, it will show the "Install Silverlight" dialog. If you don't want the dialog to show, you'll have to change the HTML source. You could add JavaScript code to add the HTML dynamically, so that it only shows when necessary. That answer would depend on how you're currently embedding the Silverlight control.

EDIT: You could try code like this:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('IsDlg=1') === -1) {
        $.getScript('/_layouts/mediaplayer.js', function () {
            mediaPlayer.createOverlayPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.attachToMediaLinks(document.getElementById('videoList'), ['wmv', 'avi', 'mp4']);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are right. But the media player code is just a .js file that came with SharePoint installation. And there is no explicit HTML embed code. It is just an hyperlink. I guess the js file dynamically searches all hyperlinks and "attaches" to it. Is there a way to remove the media player js file reference at runtime?

Comment: I'm not terribly conversant in SharePoint, so I'm not sure. Looks like you might be able to dynamically load the mediaPlayer.js file (via `jQuery.getScript` or something similar), then run your code in the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* work, so you probably want to debug for other possible issues.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     // add explicit wait until dom ready
  console.log(window.location.search);   // just to check that the parameter is present
  if(window.location.search.indexOf("IsDlg=1") < 0){   // testing the query string part only
    mediaPlayer.createOverlayPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.attachToMediaLinks(document.getElementById('videoList'), ['wmv', 'avi', 'mp4']);
   }
});
```

Try that and see how you get on.

Comment: The issue still persists I'm afraid. Console output reads `?IsDlg=1`. I'll keep looking for other possible issues.